# Change button to enabled when back button is pressed

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form that is validated by a PHP script after it is submitted. When the user clicks submit, the button text is changed to disabled What I need though is to enable it if they use the back button. I don't want to refresh the page though! This is so they don't have to fill everything back in. What I have so far.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).bind("pageshow", function() {
        document.form.submit1.innerHTML = "Submit Report";
    });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<input id="submit1" type="submit" value="Submit Report" onclick="this.disabled=true;"/>
```

Comment: A better idea would be to disable the button rather than to expect the user to read the message and actually follow it.

Comment: @AndrewArnold Good point. Changed to this suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll submit a jQuery solution as it seems like you're already using this with `$(window).bind()`.

I'd bind two events to your form element:

1. When the form is submitted, the submit button is disabled.
2. When any form element is changed (for instance when invalidated fields are updated by the user), the submit button is reenabled.

Would this work for you?

```
$('form').on({
    change: function(){
        $('#submit').prop('disabled',false);
    },
    submit: function(){
        $('#submit').prop('disabled',true);
    }
});
```

You can check out [an example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t7gMx/).